# Debugging Bitcoin Core with gdb - how to turn off compiler optimizations

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, testing, debugging

I ran the configure script with the `--enable-debug` flag, then ran `make`. I am running unit tests:

`gdb --args src/test/test_bitcoin --log_level=all --run_test=script_standard_tests`

I'm trying to step through the execution of the source files using gdb, but I am still getting `<optimized out>` for many variables, and it skips lines here and there. I thought that the `--enable-debug` flag would turn off optimization, but am I mistaken? I'm wondering if the optimization is always on for the tests or if there is a way to turn them off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitcoin Core disables `-O2` and enables `-Og` when `--enable-debug` is set. `-Og` is intended for debugging; however, it removes some of the debugging information and is buggy. To disable it and to improve debugging experience, I suggest changing [between L256 and L278](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/configure.ac#L256-L278) to:

```
CXXFLAGS="-ggdb3 -ftrapv"
```

`-ggdb3` is more powerful than `-g3`, it uses a GDB-only, LLDB-incompatible dialect for debugging. This will also get rid of `-O2`, except in libsecp256k1.

Edit: Sipa suggests a more elegant way without altering autoconf files, which is adding args for configuring.

```
./configure CXXFLAGS="-O0 -ggdb3"
```

O0 is needed in this case.

Comment: Nice workaround, thanks. I'm still getting `<optimized out>`, though, I must be missing something.

Comment: Now it is showing all variables. I must've not recompiled the file correctly.

Comment: Glad that I could help! :)

Comment: If you want to avoid all "<compiled out>"s, you need to compile with "-O0" to disable all optimizations.

Comment: Also there is no need to modify configure.ac, you can override things on the command line by using `./configure CXXFLAGS="-O0 -ggdb3" ...`.

Comment: @PieterWuille the manual (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) says O0 is default in GCC, but agree about the second, will edit soon.

Comment: @MCCCS But `--enable-debug` will pass `-Og` which overrides the `-O0` default.

Comment: Why doesn't `--enable-debug` use `-O0`?

Answer (score 1):

As of [PR #16435](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/commit/d6ac25bdd96589a71006e3ab3f303b091ffaa9e4) `--enable-debug` is actually setting "-O0", so there should be no optimization at all anymore.